# Best practice data transmission from .Net to iOS

Tags: ios, wcf, http, arrays

I have a WCF web service, once called it returns a PDF document.

I've tried 3 methods of transmitting this data and I'd just like to know what's best practice for my scenario.

Methods:

1. *Pass data back as a byte[ ] within the HTTP response body, encapsulated in JSON.*
2. *Pass data back as a base64 String within the HTTP response, encapsulated in JSON.*
3. *Save & encrypt the file to a public folder, and send the filename
   back to the app, which then get the file using [NSData
       initWithDataFromURL:.....fileName.pdf] etc.*

In all 3 scenarios, when doing more than 5 simultaneous downloads, I run into data corruption.

For a file of about **230KB**, method 1 returns a byte array size at almost **850KB**.
For that same file, method 2 returns a base64 string at around **300KB**.

For method 3 I'm still struggling with the encryption, but when doing it without encryption, the data being sent over the line is **230KB** (same as the actual file).

**This makes method 3 seem like the most efficient solution**, but I can't believe that there is not a cleaner solution than using a public folder....

How do YOU pass non-text data from your services to your iOS apps?

Comment: Have you compressed before passing it?

Comment: No, I haven't looked into compression yet, but will that not merely decrease the file's size for all 3 methods? Which still leaves me wondering, which method is best? I'll definitely still look into encryption & compression though.

Comment: I think you may want to try protobuf with compression+encryption stream instead of json with base64.

Comment: Thank you iamsleepy. If you want to add some example code as an answer it will help me alot. And then I'll also have an answer to accept.